# Appium with cordova on Android - click (onsen ui) list item by text value in js

Tags: javascript, android, list, cordova, appium

I'm trying to automate testing of an Android build of a Cordova app. I'm using onsen ui.

I have an onsen UI list containing multiple items and would like to click on one by its text value using the appium javascript API.

Is this possible? If so, please provide an example.

I've tried

```
driver.elementsByAndroidUIAutomator('new UiSelector().textContains("someUniqueText")').click()
```

This finds the text but the click fails.

I've tried a few other commands too but no luck so far! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with Xpath?

```
driver.elementByXPath("//*[@text='someUniqueText']").click()
```

This is not recommended, because * means any element... So if you can change it, your search will be faster.

`android.widget.TextView' or 
'android.widget.EditText' or 
'android.view.View',` ... (or whatever class your element is)

Comment: Great, that worked! I had tried elementByXPath() with android.widget.TextView previously but it didnt work. However both * and android.view.View worked